# "Others deem otherwise"?

Tags: grammar

I am writing an essay and have a question about it.

If I say:

> While some people say that it is a good thing, others deem otherwise.

Is it awkward?

I'm confused about the sentence 'others deem otherwise.' Is it grammatically correct? If so, does it sound natural?

Comment: It sounds ok to me.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it’s grammatical as the verb deem is both transitive and intransitive, and in this case it has the latter function.
Coming to whether it sounds natural, I have never come across such usage of deem. 
‘While some say it’s a good thing, others disagree’, seems more usual.

Answer (score 1):

> ？ While some people say that it is a good thing, others deem otherwise.

Strictly speaking, it's grammatical. However, it's unidiomatic and unnatural, and it wouldn't normally be expressed in that exact manner.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of *deem*:

> *transitive verb*
> : to come to think or judge : CONSIDER
> // *deemed* it wise to go slow
> // those whom she *deemed* worthy
> // a movie *deemed* appropriate for all ages
>
> *intransitive verb*
> : to have an opinion : BELIEVE

---

Following that, if you substitute the intransitive and synonymous *believe*, you end up with this:

> While some people say that it is a good thing, others <sup><s>deem</s></sup> believe otherwise.

However, the intransitive use of *deem* is rarely used, and I've certainly never seen it used like this.

---

It would be far more natural, and quite common, to use the transitive version of *deem*:

> ✔ While some people say that it is a good thing, others deem ***it*** otherwise.

This is not only much more idiomatic syntax, but it also preserves stylistic parallelism with the use of *it* in both parts of the sentence.

Comment: thank you so much !! it helped me a lot :)